# Does anyone know how to change the borders on the left side & right side of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to highlight the sides of the borders of an element depending on the previous URL. I can create a border around the entire element, but I just want to create a border on the left and right sides.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
var lastURL = window.location.href.split('?')
document.getElementById(lastURL[1]).style.border = '2px solid gold'
```

But, I would rather use this code:

```
var lastURL = window.location.href.split('?')
document.getElementById(lastURL[1]).style.border-left = '2px solid gold'
document.getElementById(lastURL[1]).style.border-right = '2px solid gold'
```

But, this code refuses to work and nothing happens. Does anyone know a solution to this? Is there a CSS workaround or can this be done in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to camelCase your property names, as dashes are not allowed in JavaScript property names. The interpreter will treat the dash as a subtraction operator.

```js
document.querySelector(".box").style.borderRight = "10px solid red";
document.querySelector(".box").style.borderLeft = "10px solid red";
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/1z3hx74a/3/)